# requisitos para publicar una aplicacion android

Tags: android

Existe algun requisito para publicar una aplicacion android, teniendo en cuenta que en mi pais sera complejo el acceso a play store(cuba). Realmente como soy un novato en este campo no se que hacer. La app de de salud.

Comment: Si la app es gratuita no debe haber problema, [consulta aquí](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286?hl=es). Otros enlaces que podrían servirte: [Tener una app cubana en Google Play](http://oncubamagazine.com/economia-negocios/tener-una-app-cubana-en-google-play/) y [Confirmado, ya se puede acceder a la Web Store desde Cuba](http://www.cubadebate.cu/noticias/2016/10/19/google-anuncia-desbloqueo-de-la-web-store-para-cuba-sin-resultados-visibles-hasta-el-momento/)

Comment: Aquí tienes una serie de requisitos a cummplir: http://androidbasico.com/condiciones-para-colgar-tus-aplicaciones-en-google-play.html De todas maneras, si tienes algo que no le gusta al playstore muchas veces te avisa de lo que está pasando.

Comment: Además de lo que comentan A.Cedano y Pablo, lo primero es comprar una cuenta de desarrollador: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

Comment: Comenzando porque google no da permiso para acceso a esa pagina. Debe ser por el "bloqueo", y otra parte es eso de comprar, los cubanos lo tenemos un poco dificil. Pero ademas me refiero a si existe algun documento legal , digase Ley, que rija ese proceder